# How to reuse Serverless Framework package artifacts for multiple environments?

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am using **Serverless Framework with AWS Lambda**. I have a build pipeline in which I'd like to be able to have a **single job for building** the artifact, using `sls package`, and then **2 jobs to deploy this package** to a testing and a production environment, using `sls deploy --package .serverless`.

Unfortunately, this isn't possible because Serverless packages not only contain the Lambdas' source code, but **they also contain infrastructure-specific data**, including a JSON file describing the state of the infrastructure and a cloud formation template, which are tied a specific infrastructure state (in my case testing or production).

For now, **I have to build 2 separate packages, which takes more CI time and defeats the principle of having a single immutable package**.

Has anyone found a workaround for this?
For instance, would it be possible to use `sls package` with the testing environment stage, and then **just "regenerate" the state files** for the production environment in order to save CI time?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you, but it's not possible. I also wish to build one immutable artifact for my entire pipeline. This is a limitation of Serverless Framework, or perhaps the Lambda ecosystem itself. The full answer is best documented in post over at Seed.run: https://seed.run/blog/why-serverless-deployment-artifacts-cannot-be-reused-across-stages.html

Comment: Thank you for sharing the article. While it provides some insights, I feel it doesn’t delve deep into the core reasons why a Serverless Framework artifact can’t be deployed across different stages. From my understanding, an artifact needs to make infrastructure adjustments and thus must analyze the infrastructure, generating corresponding CloudFormation code for the package to be deployed correctly. This deep-seated reason isn’t AWS Lambda specific, but more intrinsic to the Serverless Framework, blending application and infrastructure code.

Comment: Because the framework can’t guarantee identical infrastructure states across dev, pre-prod, or prod, an artifact becomes environment-dependent. However, I believe there’s a way to reuse artifacts in some manner, though I haven’t fully tested it. Using sls deploy bundles CloudFormation files for infrastructure modifications, but I think sls deploy -f only uploads the source code, which would be faster.

Comment: I wonder if there’s a way to have CI/CD check if a full sls deploy is necessary, e.g., for new functions or added infrastructure dependencies like an API gateway. But if there are no such additions (e.g., the serverless.ts file remains unchanged), perhaps CI/CD could only execute sls deploy -f for specific functions. I’ve yet to test this approach.

Comment: A side note: the article mentions reusing an artifact for rollback. While this may be true for most cases, I believe there are situations where it wouldn’t work. For instance, if an artifact doesn’t anticipate updating an AWS Lambda layer that was later modified by a subsequent artifact and we want to rollback, it wouldn’t be feasible.